# Multiple .local hostname on one computer

Tags: dns, apache, smb, bonjour, hosts

Is possible setup multiple `.local` hostname on one physical computer?

Background:

- home network (behind the DSL/NAT router) (192.168.1.*)
- have a mac-mini, called as "tango.local". (set in the System.prefs). The IP-setting is "use DHCP with manual address" - the computer address is 192.168.1.10.

Now, on this mac want run `apache2` (macports version), with different `VirtualHost` directives, like:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName tango.local
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:5000/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:5000
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName another.local
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:3000/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:3000
</VirtualHost>
```

For this setup I need assign two different hostnames to the mac, e.g. the main `tango.local` and the `another.local`. Both names should be `resolve-able` from the LAN, e.g. computers on the LAN (my mac-notebook) must correctly resolve the `http://another.local/` address.

It is possible to do this with simple way, (e.g. somewhat convience the bonjour to advertise both names for the single IP), or need setup the `bind` DNS server for serving the `.local` domain?

Bonus question: the main goal is resolve the `another.local` from another mac (via bonjour). Secondary: what i need setup to allow access the `http://another.local` from an windows7 notebook? (i'm total windiot - e.g. is possible somewhat convert bonjour names-addresses to the "windows `nmbd`" or whatever?

Comment: Hey, I've updated my answer below after realising it's totally possible to register multiple `.local` names simply by using the dns-sd proxy option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you don't need to register a new hostname if you're just about publishing web services.
On the Mac, you can register a new website with bonjour on the command line with

```
dns-sd -R "My Website" _http._tcp . 80 path=/path-to-page.html
```

you can verify that it worked by using Safari's bonjour menu or on the command line with

```
dns-sd -B _http._tcp
```

Bonjour for Windows is available (and is, I think, included when installing iTunes).

If for some reason you actually *need* specific host names, you could consider using dnsmasq (can be installed with homebrew or macports) to reroute your specific hostnames only (using your default DNS for everything else) and telling your Windows computer to use your Mac as its DNS server.

---

### Update:

I failed to realise it's totally possible, you can indeed register multiple .local hostnames with bonjour, do it as a proxy like this:

```
dns-sd -P myService1 _http._tcp local 80 server1.local 127.0.0.1 path=/path/to/service1
dns-sd -P myService2 _http._tcp local 80 server2.local 127.0.0.1 path=/path/to/service2
```

Here you're registering two services (myService1,-2) running on the same server (127.0.0.1, within different server paths) on port 80 as two different .local names.

Comment: Note that using "127.0.0.1" will make the hostname work like "localhost" on all local machines.  If you want to connect to the new hostname from another machine on the network, use its LAN IP address.